# How can I change element constantly based on window.innerWidth resize?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change element dynamically according to window width. It should change to a new element when condition is met, as well as revert back to the original element when window is restored to its original size. Here's my code attached:

HTML

```
<div>
  <h1>My Name</h1>
</div>
```

JS

```
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(window.innerWidth);
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if(window.innerWidth <=1000){
      parentDiv.innerHTML = '<p>lorem Ipsum</p>'
    }
})
```

But here, after changing back the window size to a width of >1000px, the `div` tag still holds `p` tag instead of reverting back to the original `h1` tag. Should I add another event listener for this specific task? Or is there any other method of `window` object by which we can achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you just need to add an `else` statement to your code. In the `else` statement is where you would set the `innerHTML` back to your original HTML. It should also be noted you could do this with CSS and media queries to show/hide the appropriate elements on the page.

Comment: Thank you so much, the solution was obvious yet I failed to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, simply add an `else` statement to revert back to the `<h1>`:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if(window.innerWidth <=1000){
    parentDiv.innerHTML = '<p>lorem Ipsum</p>'
  } else {
    parentDiv.innerHTML = '<h1>My Name</h1>'
  }
})
```

FYI, using CSS media queries is a lot more efficient than listening to the window resize event:

- https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries